# Verify the following identity for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

[image: Identity for Fibonacci numbers]

This is a homework problem that I would very much appreciate some help with. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Just consider $$F_{n} F_{n+1} - F_{n-1} F_{n} = F_{n} (F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}) = F_{n}^{2}.$$
This suggests a certain method of proof.

Answer (score 1):

One could proceed by inductin as follows:
For $n=0$, both sides are $1$. For $n=1$, both sides are $2$.
Suppose now that it holds for $n=k\ge 1$. Then $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}F_i^2=F_kF_{k+1}+F_{k+1}^{2}=F_{k+1}(F_k+F_{k+1})=F_{k+1}F_{k+2}$.

Comment: Of course this cannot be compared with the elegant and powerful solution of Andreas Caranti.

Comment: I could be wrong but in my opinion they're equivalent. Your proof is based on the same identity.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee, you're right, it's exactly the same. It's just that, in the spirit of homework (which I am not sure to follow consistently) I pointed OP in the direction of a proof by induction.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti If you consider this as invasing your copyright, or if you want, I will delete this answer. Just thought that a full answer might help, though.

Comment: @awllower, thanks, but it's perfectly ok to me.